# Passport.js signup appears to work but user credentials not inserted into database

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, sequelize.js

Using [Scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local) and the [official passport docs](http://passportjs.org/) as reference, I'm implementing a Node/Express/Sequelize application where I have a basic signup form with fields for email and password:

### ./views/signup.ejs

```
<form action="/signup" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Signup</button>
</form>
```

with the passport-local strategy defined as follows:

### ./config/passport.js

```
const db = require('./sequelize');

const passport = require('passport'), 
LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    db.User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({
    emailField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true
    }, 
    function(email, password, done){
        process.nextTick(function() {
            // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
            // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
            db.User.findOne({ email : email }, function(err, user) {
                // if there are any errors, return the error
                if (err)
                    return done(null, false, {message: err});

                // check to see if theres already a user with that email
                if (user) {
                    return done(null, false, {message: 'User already exists'});
                } 

                else {
                    // if there is no user with that email
                    // create the user
                    db.User.create({
                        email: email,
                        password: password
                    });
                    return done(null, false, {message: 'User created'});
                }
            });    
         });
      }
 ));

module.exports = passport;
```

and lastly the routes are taken care of in

### app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('./config/sequelize');
const querystring = require('querystring');
const config = require('./config/config');
const passport = require('./config/passport');
const bodyParser = require( 'body-parser' );

const env = 'development';

const app = express();

const port = 3000;

app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }) );
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.listen(port);

app.post('/signup', function(req, res, next){

const user = req.body;
passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info){
        if (err){ 
            res.send({success: false, message: 'authentication failed'}); 
        }
        else{
            console.log(info);
            res.json({message: "success"});
        }
    })(req, res, next)
});
```

What I expect to happen if the local strategy works is for the res.json({message: "success"}) to appear on the browser and for the database to be updated per the specifications of ./config/passport.js. The {message: "success"} is appearing on the screen, but the database is not being updated, which leads me to believe that something is wrong with my implementation in ./config/passport.js. In app.js, the console.log(info) statement shows the following message on cmd:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `createdAt`, 
`updatedAt` FROM `Users` AS `User` LIMIT 1;
```

which makes it look like the insertions might be going through but inspections of the db reveal otherwise. I have done previous sanity checks with CRUD updates to confirm that the basic implementation of Sequelize works, and will provide the schema of the table upon request. How else can I debug this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Read about how to make queries in sequelize
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/
you should use promises, like this:

```
db.User.findOne({ where: {email : email }})
.then(function(user){
   //do smth;
})
.catch(function(error){ 
   console.log(error); 
});
```